# Is there any way to get sources of an internal class and its all related classes from .net framework?

Tags: c#

I get sources of classes from http://referencesource.microsoft.com but errors increase continuously when I try to add needed classes for a class. Is there any way to get sources of an internal class and its all related classes from .net framework?

Comment: what do you mean by "errors increase when add needed classes"? do you copy & paste the code from referencesource?

Comment: Yes. I copy & paste the code.

Comment: I want to get sources of an internal class that I can use in my project.

Comment: You mean a disassembler? Try http://ilspy.net/

Comment: thats not the intended way of using the code from referncesource. Referncesource is just a documentation for reference. You can look into and see how it is implemented what you're using in your code. If you want to use a class you have to (maybe) add a reference to your project add a using and make use of them in your classes and code. Maybe you should provide a little example what you're trying to do

Comment: My problem is that I want to create a derived class of an internal class that can't not be used from out of it's assembly. Event if I get sources from  http://referencesource.microsoft.com or ILSpy, I can get only the class I want. For its related classes, I must get them manually. Is there any ways to get all of them.